# Django adding dict to template as a table

Tags: python, django, django-templates

How can I add dictionary to a template nicely with Django - 
Just want all the information in a nice table.

I have the following dict:

```
{'Information': {0: 'size', 1: 'energy [kWh]', 2: 'ratio [PR]'}, 'Value': {0: 570.66, 1: 984092.66, 2: 81.7}}
```

Tried to use  `{% for v in values[0] %}` - ***Could not parse the remainder: '[0]' from 'values[0]'***

HTML Part

```
         <div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Information</th>
                    <th>Value</th>
                </tr>
                    <tr>
                        {% for key, values in dict_data.items %}
                        {% for v in values %}
                        <td>{{v}}</td>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
            </table>
        </div>
```

It's resulting with that:
[image]

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your HTML matches what you say is resulting; your `Information` header is before the `Value` header, but in your output `Value` comes first. Also, you only have two headers `<th>`, but your nested dictionaries have 3 values, so the way you currently process the data will result in more cells in the table body than headers.

Another issue: your `values` is a dict also, so `{% for v in values %}` just gets you the keys (`0`, `1`, `2`) of the nest dict, and you never get the nested values (`size`, `energy [kWh]`, `ratio [PR]`). You probably want something like:

```
{% for key, values in dict_data.items %}
{% for sub_key, sub_value in values.items %}
```

Also: you are processing one key/value set per row, so the first row of your table will have the `Information` values, and the second row will have the `Value` values (or vice-versa), but what you want is one value from Information and one value from Value per row. So ultimately you will need to structure your data differently (as pairs, perhaps).

Instead of your current structure, I'd have information/value pairs:

```
dict_data = {'Information': {0: 'size', 1: 'energy [kWh]', 2: 'ratio [PR]'}, 'Value': {0: 570.66, 1: 984092.66, 2: 81.7}}
info_value_pairs = [('size', 570.66), ('energy [kWh]', 984092.66), ('ratio [PR]', 81.7)]
```

and then in your template:

```
{% for pair in info_value_pairs %}
<tr><td>{{ pair.0 }}</td><td>{{ pair.1 }}</td></tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: If you have only the dict I mentioned - `{'Information': {0: 'size', 1: 'energy [kWh]', 2: 'ratio [PR]'}, 'Value': {0: 570.66, 1: 984092.66, 2: 81.7}}` - How would you write HTML table with all the keys and the nested values?

Comment: Also there's anything more comfortable than dict for that purpose?  (I had a dataframe I converted to dict) - THANK YOU!

Comment: What way would you recommend to structure the data for that?

Comment: I added an example of how to pass the data differently, and use it (on pair of Info/Value per row)